# Is returning an array of structs possible yet?

Tags: solidity, contract-design

From what I can tell this should be possible now:

```
function test2 () public view returns (Post[]) {
        Post memory post;
        post.sender = msg.sender;
        post.link = "test";
        post.category = "test";
        post.comment = "test";
        post.timestamp = now;

        Post[] storage postsOnPage;
        postsOnPage.push(post);

        return postsOnPage;
    }
```

Unfortunately I get this error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Invalid solidity type: tuple[]
```

I'm using web3 version 1. 
If its not supported any ideas for a workaround?

Thanks!